# How can I prevent my controller from loading before a promise from app.run is resolved?

Tags: angularjs

If this is not possible, I'm open to any solution.

I have an `alerts` factory, which holds an array that is populated with alerts from an API call on `app.run`.

I also have a `units` controller, which sets a `$scope.unit_alerts` variable equal to the alerts associated with that specific unit page.  The problem is that, around 10% of the time, the units controller tries to set the scope variable before the `alerts` factory is done loading the API call, leading to an undefined error.

I know about using UI-router to prevent the page from loading before a promise is resolved, but in this scenario I need the alerts to be available across the entire application, regardless of if the `unit` page is the first loaded page.  Therefore, I can't put the dependency in the unit route because it won't be available for the rest of the application.

```
angular.module('app').run(['alerts,function(alerts){
  // some code to get user and units  
  alerts.populate(user._id, units)
}];

angular.module('app').factory('alerts, function($http){
var o = {};
o.alerts = [];

o.populate = function(user_id, units){
 return $http.get('/api/users/alerts/' + user_id).then(function(res){
   res.data.forEach(function(alert){
        o.alerts.push(alert);
   });
  });
});

return o;
});

angular.module('app').config(['stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider.state('units', {
  url: '/units/{id}',
  templateUrl: '../unit.html',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  controller: 'UnitsCtrl',
  resolve: {
    unit: ['$stateParams', 'units',
      function ($stateParams, units) {
        return units.get($stateParams.id);
      }
    ]
  }
});

});


angular.module('app').controller('UnitsCtrl', ['alerts', function(alerts){

 $scope.unit_alerts = alerts.alerts

});
```

Comment: I think providing the code of your factory/controller would be helpful :)

Comment: Not enough info. Where is controller in your code, how is it loading?

Comment: Added the relevant code

Comment: Use the ngRoute or uiRouter resolve attribute. see https://johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/ and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Like I said though I need it to be available for the entire application regardless of which page is loaded originally

Comment: So use an abstract state and let all the other states be a child of that state, so no matter what page is loaded, is will be resolved because each child state resolves all his parents resolves as well. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!!